# HTTP header Content-Disposition "attachement" (rather than "attachment")

Tags: http-headers, content-disposition

I'm writing code to read an HTTP response, and I'm seeing

```
 Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=xxxx
```

It looks like [rfc2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) is the relevant standard, and it says "attachment".  Searching around, I can't find anything about why a server might be returning "attachement" instead.  (Part of the problem seems to be that lots of people seem to be using "attachement" as the correct spelling of the word.)

I did find a few pages ([example](http://dotanything.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/content-disposition-attachment-vs-inline/)) suggesting that IE doesn't (or didn't at one point) handle "attachment" correctly -- is this a case where everyone started writing around a bug and that's now become the standard?

If that is the case, should I consider attachment/attachement to be meaningless, and treat anything with a filename as downloadable?  Or should I explicitly handle either word?

Also, in this particular case, the server belongs to my organization, and they are trying to keep everything standards-based -- can I legitimately file a bug report for this?

Comment: Good point. Why do we have 'management' and not 'managment' (equipement vs equipment, probably from the french language) !? You also have similar dangerous cases with width, height, light, weight, ... I have some custom code checker to find those in my projects ... will add attachement to those !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant specification is RFC 6266 (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html), and it says that unknown disposition types should be treated as "attachment" (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.4.2).

With respect to the example you cite: no, IE does support "attachment" (and has forever). The problem over there might have had to do with nonsense caching response headers.

Answer (score -1):

A conspiracy theorist might note that the HTML standards are based in Paris and attachement is a French spelling but as already noted the specified behaviour is to treat unrecognised strings as attachment, so it might be a typo or it might be French people not noticing that they used a French spelling because they get the expected behaviour. Possibly both.